# A program to log how much time you spend in what program

Tags: windows, time-management

Seems like there should be something. Basically it should provide a report:

- With the total time spent in program X
- With a graph of how much time was spent in program X at what time of day (think the [OPSR Github graph of activity](http://osrc.dfm.io/pacificmorrowind#day))
- That works on Windows

Bonus:

- Time spent actively engaged (*Very optional* since I'm not even entirely sure how would be a good way to calculate that - perhaps time typing/mouse clicking or within 5 seconds of that?)
- Page address in browser(s)
- Filename in things like other programs (obviously that wouldn't apply to all other programs but thinking of e.g. notepad++, MS Word, MS Excel)
- Open Source
- Gratis

Comment: Linux `time` command gives you runtime of a specific console program. say, `time pine` will tell you how long you spent reading your mail. (of course not OP's requirements so posting as a comment)

Comment: Isn't `time` about CPU time? For instance, even if you read emails for 1 hour, your CPU has probably only spent a few seconds on this.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/) is a pretty awesome piece of software (free/pro with trial).
It let's you track time by theme dimensions:

1. Usage (Active or not)
2. Application used
3. Document (title of the document)
4. Tags

The pro version (also have trial) even let's you auto-tag time by using filters to select specific keywords. for example you can auto-tag all the time you spend in *facebook.com/* under 'Social networking'.

It can also give you reports in the end of the month/week/day!

I love it...

Comment: and it ships with a [portable version](http://www.manictime.com/Download/)

Comment: Is there a way to merge the data from two computers (home / office) without the server?

Comment: No, you need to use a server to do that. However server is just a simple app, you can run it on one of the machines and set both instances to send data to it.

Answer (score 27):

I've had some success with [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com). It tracks software used, webpages visited, and has a free version too.

Not open source though. If you're willing to do all the tracking yourself (e.g. I do this at work for loosely tracking projects) then I can recommend [toggl](http://toggl.com).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I second RescueTime and use it myself. It will automatically send you a weekly summary, it can trigger notifications at certain limits, groups applications and websites nicely into categories and more.

Comment: RescueTime is your answer, look no further

Comment: Note that the free version doesn't track individual filenames. E.g. if you spend 1 hour reading A.pdf and 2 hours reading B.pdf on Adobe Acrobat, the free version will only tell you that you spent 3 hours on Adobe Acrobat. It won't give you the breakdown.

Answer (score 14):

[**ProcrastiTracker**](http://strlen.com/procrastitracker/) is an **open source** time tracking tool for Windows that automatically tracks what applications and documents you use, and allows you to view statistics on your usage in great detail:

[image: ProcrastiTracker]

Answer (score 12):

I use [WhatPulse](http://www.whatpulse.org/):

- Free
- Win/Mac/[Linux](https://help.whatpulse.org/kb/client/linux-installation)
- It records the total time spent in each program, but it doesn't do any of your bonus features and doesn't have the graph of how much time was spent in program X at what time of day.
- Stats are [available online](http://www.whatpulse.org/Franck.Dernoncourt#apps) as well as on the desktop client.
- Support several computers
- It records the number of clicks per application:

[image]

- As a [premium service](http://www.whatpulse.org/pages/premium-services/) you can have a per application uptime chart
  [image]

Answer (score 7):

I can recommend my own software [WAYD](http://www.gljakal.com/wayd/)!

In addition to tracking the active program (it records the program name and the window title),
every x minutes it will pop up a window that covers your entire screen and asks you, "What are you doing?"

I find that, while it's a little bit annoying, most of the time just knowing which programs were open is not very useful. Having to **write** what I'm doing however keeps me honest  and focused on what's important.

And at the end of the month, my boss gets a nice report where all of my working hours are accounted for :)

Plus, it's free and all the data is stored locally on your computer.

So here are the features:

- Reports with total time spent on each application, with app name and window title
- Works on Windows
- No fancy charts, but can export data as CSV to be used in any spreadsheet software

Bonus:

- No filename or address, but can show you the window title
- Free
- (optionally) Directly asks you what you are doing

Comment: Sounds good – but could you please include which of the OPs requirements are covered? Thanks!

Comment: Why is it closed-source? You don't seem to be making any money off it.

Comment: @Navin People are not obligated to make their software open source, nor to explain their reasoning for it being closed-source, just because it's free.  Perhaps you intended to ask a more polite question, such as, "Have you ever considered making your software open-source, so others could help you work on it?"

Comment: @Kyralessa Nope, I just asked him why. I'm not asking him to consider anything.

Comment: @Navin You..._didn't_ intend to ask a more polite question?  Oh, well, my apologies for thinking so.  But "You don't seem to be making any money off it" implies that making money off a program is the only reason to make it closed-source, which is far from correct.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Visual TimeAnalyzer](http://www.neuber.com/timeanalyzer/):

- non-free
- Log individual users or specific projects, and compile detailed accounts of time spent within each program.
- Track work time, pauses, projects, costs, software and internet use.
- Track visited web pages
- Windows 8 (excl. Apps), 7, Vista, XP, 2000 or Windows Server

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've been using RescueTime lately.

I install an agent on my Devices (Desktop and Mobile)
This is linked to my account and it keeps track of what apps I actively use on these devices.

If during my work  hours I leave my desk for a period of time (configurable, mine is 5 minutes) it will prompt me for what I was doing. (Meeting, Support, Other). These can also be customized I believe.

At any given time I can login to their portal and view graphs and charts on software used, my perceived productiveness, and manage which apps are deemed productive, neutral, or Distracting.

It can go as far as reading the web page title/address from the most popular browsers.

Here I've included an example of a high level overview of my day so far so you can see if it's for you.

[image: Daily Dashboard Overview]