# Free Desktop Time Tracker / Keylogger Productivity Software

Tags: windows, time-management, productivity

I am looking for a free(can be open source) time tracking software which performs functions similar to [RescueTime](http://rescuetime.com) but is not network-dependent, i.e it does not sync to a server but remains on my system only. Preferably, it can also integrate a keylogger. I am running Windows 8.

Comment: other than the keylogger the answers [on my old question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/107) should be a pretty good match.

Comment: Thanks @NickWilde Exactly what I was looking for.