# Program to log how long each program was displayed in each monitor

Tags: time-management, multi-monitor

I am looking for a program that can

- record how long each program was displayed in each monitor (e.g. for each monitor show graph of how much time was spent in program X at what time of day).
- runs on Windows 7 or Ubuntu

It would basically be an extension of [A program to log how much time you spend in what program](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/903) to support multi-monitor.