# Daily activity recorder for windows?

Tags: windows, web-apps, software-development

Is there any application that automatically tracks our day to day work and log for future reference or simple application to input hourly task?

The tasks like,

Work done each 30 mins, 
attended meetings, 
after work spent time on tasks.

Comment: simple application to input hourly task -> Excel? automatically tracks our day to day work  -> http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/903 ?

Comment: What do you want to track - ie what program? actual output? more details required ;)

Comment: sorry, i updated the question.

Comment: Evernote is a good app, although it's not a Windows app, but a web one. Not sure if that's what you need, but it's a handy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [ManicTime](http://www.manictime.com/), it is a portable application that helps you to track the time that you have spent on applications in your computer. There is a professional version too, but standard free version should help you. I have written an article on ManicTime in my blog [here](http://www.articpost.com/time-spent-on-facebook/).