# Time Tracker / Planner With Outlook Integration

Tags: time-management

I'm after some software / plugin that allows users to:

- Plan their day.
- Record what they actually did.
- Compare the variance.

Ideally it will have some form of Outlook integration. Detailed reporting would also be useful.

We previously used a hacked together (and I mean hacked) excel spreadsheet that threw an exception as often as it worked - management are insisting on a stable replica.

I'm not so interested in recording program use, i.e.:

[A program to log how much time you spend in what program](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/696/a-program-to-log-how-much-time-you-spend-in-what-program)

Any help much appreciated

Comment: Outlook would be my recommendation as well.  Outlook is designed specifically to do these things.  How do you plan to track Items 2 and 3 on your list?  If the answer is "have the person report it" then outlook is a good choice.

Comment: Maybe "Efficient To-Do List"?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use what you already have: Outlook - it includes a packages called Journal & Tasks that allows you to track time and progress.

If you are on an exchange server these can be shared and task progress automatically reported to those that set the task.

Lots of different reports are available see [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/track-your-time-in-outlook-using-journal-HA010034346.aspx) for a good write up.

Answer (score -1):

You can try Time Tracker Outlook Add-in

[www.ahausoftware.com/time-tracker-outlook](http://www.ahausoftware.com/time-tracker-outlook)

[image]

Comment: This seems to only count the time spent writing emails - that's not what the OP wants.