# Activity/time tracking

Tags: gratis, time-management

I want to track how much time I spend on doing what on my computer and how much time I spend on it in general. Are there any good free programs already?

If not, I just would program a small program myself, as I want it to detect when I go AFK or the time tracking won't be worth anything to me.

The sole purpose of the whole thing is to plan my free time at the computer a bit better and look at how much time I spend on something and whether or not I consider it worth the time.

Comment: For which operating system? If you're looking for a Windows program, then I think your question is a duplicate of this: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/6834

Answer (score 4):

The best freee tool for time tracking with AFK is [Grindstone](http://www.epiforge.com/Grindstone/)
The only problem with that tool is if you are workingon differtent locations and wants to merge times. In such case I would recommend [Toggl](https://toggl.com/) This one has desktop tool with AFK but not good