# Simple time tracking application

Tags: web-apps, time-management, reporting

I am looking for an application to track my time spend on different projects. Let's say I have about 3-4 project and in every of them I work on 5-10 tasks. I often switch between the projects, so it must be easy and quick.

So my requirements:

- multiple projects
- simple switching between tasks and between projects
- some monthly reports (and possibility to export them)

I don't need much more — some pretty charts would be nice, but not necessary. It would be also nice to share the reports, but I can download them and send in the mail, no big deal.

Comment: Does it have to be a web application? Would something running locally, possibly sharing data via something like drive, be suitable? What platform(s) if so?

Comment: I prefer web application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity/time tracking](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/14128/activity-time-tracking)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've already tried all well-known time trickers like toggl.com, hubstaff.com etc. Nice list of time trackers is here: http://timetrackerlist.com/

Quite new web application https://www.pichacky.net could be also interesting for you. It is simple, but provides exactly what you need.

You have a big blank space and you can create blocks by double-clicking. Ordinary you create one block for every project you have.

[image: You have a big blank space and you can create blocks by double-clicking.]

The syntax of block is really simple, you have to write `[ ]` before every line which should be considered as task.

By clicking somewhere to space or by pressing the ESC key the block is saved. If you want to start track time for some of tasks, you just click to its line.

[image: Start tracking task]

Pichacky.net provides simple history with monthly views and possibility to export to csv or print the page.

[image: History]

The application is still in beta, but it is pretty stable.

Comment: pichacky seems gone.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at MoneyPenny [Time Tracking](https://moneypenny.me/en/tour-the-app/time-tracking) - you simply can add clients, projects and tasks switch between in a second, track your time and issue an invoice if needed. You can also generate reports for any time range needed. I use it myself and its perfect! :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest https://toggl.com, best time tracking app i ever saw. It supports infinite projects, tasks and reports in it's free plan. It even has a mobile app and browser intergration (for Google doc, Trello and other stuff)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a time-tracking Windows desktop program (Timesheet Sidekick) which appears to meet the requirements of this question.  (I do see that the question has a "web-apps" tag, but the text of the question does not mention the need for the software to be web-based.)

There is a 15-minute overview video on the web site:

http://www.timesheetsidekick.com/