# measuring time spent on tasks

Tags: windows, linux, project-management, time-management

I'd like to know how much time I've spent usefully and how much time I've wasted in a day/week/month. This could be done with a program, that one triggers when a task starts and when a task ends, recording the amount of time in between the triggers and then keeping stats in a database. Does some program, that allows this, exist for Windows or Linux?

Comment: For Windows, I recommend the accepted answer on [this question: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/6834](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/696/6834)

Comment: I had some nice ideas for Android, where starting/stopping the timer could even be accomplished via QR-Codes or NFC tags to make things easier – but I understand that's not what was asked for :)

Comment: Yup, @Timmy was correct. This question should be closed as duplicate (which I currently don't have the rep to do)

Comment: @Mawg The question has the Linux tag. It's why I'm hesitant to mark it as duplicate until we have a response from the OP.

Comment: @Timmy the links are fine, but I'd prefer Linux suggestions to Windows ones. Nevertheless, you can mark it as a duplicate, if you think it appropriate.

Comment: @user1095108 If you are interested in a Linux software, then I think the question is still relevant, but it's better if you edit it to convey that

Answer (score 3):

**[Time Doctor](http://www.timedoctor.com)** seems to be a perfect fit for the requirements you mentioned.

It tracks your time with the simple trigger of a go button. And, you can click break when you are not working.

[image: Time Tracking]

And yes, it stores everything in a database/dashboard. It's like giving you an analytics of your workday.

[image: Dashboard]

It's also open source. So, it works with **Windows**, **Linux** and **OS X**.

If you are interested, you can check more of its features here:
http://www.timedoctor.com/features.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are OK with an online version I suggest [RescueTime](https://www.rescuetime.com/). It installs some software on your computer, then monitors every executable you use and all webpages you visit.

These are all categorized (an advantage of being a centrally hosted solution) and after some time it shows you the time spent in these categories (either in your browser and/or my weekly email overview).

It 'knows' a large amount of programs/websites and those it does not recognize you can add to the categories. The categories you can lump together in productive/not-productive time, so that in its top-most aggregate you get a "percentage productive time".

The paid version has more facilities than the free one, but I suggest you give the free version a try first.

Answer (score 2):

For a windows solution I would suggest [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com). It is primarily a project/task management solution, but it has exactly the time tracking specification you have described.

With Eylean time tracking can be done automatically, with a trigger to stop if you have been idle for a while, or manually, where you simply input the time spent on tasks. You can always use a mix of both as well. Besides the software has a variety of features and is really easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

## [KTimeTracker](https://www.kde.org/applications/utilities/ktimetracker/)

KTimeTracker is a task management utility from KDE. It tracks how long you spend on different tasks and stores the records in portable formats. It allows you to:

- Organize tasks into subtasks up to some 1000 levels
- Edit task history and comments
- Detect pauses. It stops recording when the computer is idle for a configurable amount of time
- The time history can be exported to a comma-delimited text file for importing into other billing and/or project management tools.

  <sup>([Source](https://userbase.kde.org/KTimeTracker))</sup>

It can be installed on Linux or Windows, but it comes as part of the [**Kontact**](https://userbase.kde.org/Kontact) suit and has to be installed along with all the other components.