# Recreate a timeline of what someone did

Tags: time-management

[These recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/696/a-program-to-log-how-much-time-you-spend-in-what-program), are good for tracking your own usage, but I have an attorney that wants to recreate a timeline of what someone was working on after the fact.
He is able to subpoena their records, so he can get their email and create a timeline of what was said and when, but he wants to know if there is any software that can combine other date/time related data. Phone calls, both office and personal cell phone. Text messages. Browsing history. Chat room activity.  Files edited. Something to put all of these bits of information together. I told him "it's called Excel".

This involves a court case where the plaintiff is suing for being charged too many hours.