# Software to track the amount of time using a specific software automatically

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, time-management

I need a software to track how much time I spend on a specific software, like Chrome, Photoshop or Blender, but I can only find either closed source options or software that do not work on Linux.

So it would be programs that match this:

- Works on linux (arch preferably)
- Open source
- If possible tracks the amount of actual usage time:that could be through the amount of time with the window actually active or any other parameter.

Comment: I would post this as an answer, but you specified it has to be open source, so this recommendation won't cut it there, but it's possible this company which has been around for a while started some github project or in some other way contributed to another project.  https://www.rescuetime.com/  They have a linux client, not sure which distro.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a github. I'll check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at [ManicTime](https://www.manictime.com/linux/download), that can help with tracking time spent in programs. The free version may be sufficient for your needs. They have versions for Linux and Windows.

You will find a few other options to try out in a [previous answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/696/a-program-to-log-how-much-time-you-spend-in-what-program).

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that question here, as well as ManicTime, although I want an Open Source software :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check out [Activity Watch](https://activitywatch.net/). 
It's an open source alternative to Rescue time. You'll need to check if it's mature enough for your needs.